# how to use if statement for ui label in Xcode swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

my code:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    

    var score = 0
    
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    
    @IBAction func textfield(_ sender: Any) {
         
        
    }
    @IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {


    
  let imageName = "FB copy-3.png"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 64.5, y: 413.5, width: 100, height: 100); view.addSubview(imageView)

        Counterlabel.text = String(score)
        
        if score >= 500 && score <= 998 {
            
            score += 2
            imageView.image = UIImage(named:"500button")
        }
        else if score >= 998 && score <= 1995 {
            
            score += 5
        }
        else if score >= 1995 && score <= 4000 {
            
            score += 10
            imageView.image = UIImage(named:"2000button")
           
        }
        else if score >= 4000 && score <= 10000 {
            
            score += 20
            
        }
        else if score >= 10000 && score <= 25000 {
            score += 50
        }
        else if score >= 25000 && score <= 75000 {
            
            score += 100
            
        }
        else if score >= 75000{
            
            score += 250
            
        }
        else {
            
            score += 1
            
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonimage(_ sender: Any) {
        
    }
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Counterlabel: UILabel!
}
```

so ive recently started coding and dont know much i wanted to create a small game and heres my problem:

i firstly want to add a cheat code in my game so i have a text label and i want it so that if my text labels text is 1811 (or anything works) then score += 50000

that is the problem i have been facing

also a more important thing (if possible) i really want to know how to save gtame data so if played again the progress is saved.
the only progress i want to save is the number.

a leader board would also be nice

any of the above would help i really appreciate it.

this is how my story board looks:

[main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adtSu.png)

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem in the label.

Answer (score 0):

you can use UserDefaults to save the score:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

defaults.set(25, forKey: "score")

defaults.set("ESRAA", forKey: "Name")
```

check this link for more details: [https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults](http://example)

Answer (score 0):

```
As per my understanding,
```

1. Toxic you can add UITextField, and set it's delegate,

   > textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: [TextField_Delegates_Detail](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate)

   Where you can set check,

   if textfield.text == "1811"
   {
   score += 50000
   }
2. For saving and Storing game Data, You can use UserDefaults, CoreData, SQLite database that IOS Supports. [Some_Basic_Detail](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ios-application-security-part-20-local-data-storage-nsuserdefaults-coredata-sqlite-plist-files/#gref)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like to check the textField value

```
if textField.text == "11811" { socre += 5000 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To consider the text field value connect the `delegate` of the text field to the controller and implement

```
@objc func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField : UITextField) {
    if textField.text! != "1811" { return }
    score += 50000
    UserDefaults.standard.set(score, forKey: "score")
}
```

The benefit is that the check is not performed permanently when a key is pressed. The value is saved to `UserDefaults`. Delete the `IBAction`

In `viewDidLoad` load the value form `UserDefaults`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    score = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "score")
}
```

The range check can be written more efficiently

```
@IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {
    let imageName = "FB copy-3.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 64.5, y: 413.5, width: 100, height: 100)
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    
    Counterlabel.text = String(score)
    switch score {
        case 500..<998:
            score += 2
            imageView.image = UIImage(named:"500button")
        case 998..<1995:
            score += 5
        case 1995..<4000:
            score += 10
            imageView.image = UIImage(named:"2000button")
        case 4000..<10000:
            score += 20
        case 10000...25000:
            score += 100
        case 75000...:
            score += 250
        default:
            score += 1
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(score, forKey: "score")
}
```

I doubt that adding an(other) image view is intended whenever the button is pressed

---

And please name variables like `Button` and `Counterlabel` *lowerCamelCased*: `button` and `counterLabel`

Comment: hi, thanks for your response with your code im getting two errors one is for the obj func it says that value of type any has no member text. the second is for making my over all code better it says that only instance methods can be declared @ibaction

Comment: First error: My bad, it's a typo (`textField.text`). Second error I don't understand.

Comment: also when i use the code and run the game then the clicks dont increase

Comment: What does *clicks don't increase* mean?

Comment: also my data didnt save (sorry for the trouble)

Comment: so whenever i hit a button then on the top right clicks should increase aka counterlabel

Comment: Is the `IBAction` called at all? Set a breakpoint to check that or insert a `print` line

Comment: is there a way i can mail you my files so you can improve and send back cuz that way you can run the code to check? and also edit

Comment: I'm afraid, no. I'd like to help but only on this site.

Comment: okay, then here is my improved code can you help i dont understand the save data part